# When is map between $H^1$ of curves injective?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given a morphism $f\colon X \to Y$ of smooth projective curves over $\overline{\mathbb F_p}$, when can one expect the map 
$$H^1(Y,\mathcal O_Y) \to H^1(X,f^*\mathcal O_Y) = H^1(X,\mathcal O_X)$$
to be injective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the map is not constant, otherwise clearly the map is zero. If $p$ does not divide $\deg f$, then the inclusion $\mathcal{O}_Y\to f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ splits by the trace map and thus the map you want is injective. May be separability of $f$ is enough, but am not sure. If inseparable (for example, the Frobenius), things can go wrong, like in the case of supersingular curves.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am not quite sure what "splits by the trace map" means. Do you think you could elaborate on that, or is there a good reference where I could learn about this?

Comment: @user476477 This is standard and can be found in any book. You have the trace map $f_*\mathcal{O}_X\to \mathcal{O}_Y$, for any finite map, as long as as $Y$ is normal. If $p$ does not divide the degree of $f$, this map is non-zero, since on $\mathcal{O}_Y$, the trace is just multiplication by the degree.

Comment: Dear @Mohan, Could you please explain why the trace is just multiplication by the degree? If I am not wrong the degree of $f$ is the dimension of its fibers and unless $f$ is flat, the dimension may vary from a point $x\in X$ to a point $x'\in X$?

Comment: @user476477 Finite map of smooth curves is always flat. Locally on $Y$, the map on regular functions looks like $A\subset B$, where $B$ is a free module over $A$ of rank $\deg f=n$. Trace is defined as: if $b\in B$, then multiplication by $b$ on $B$ can be represented as an $n\times n$ matrix over $A$ and take its trace. For, $a\in A$, multiplication is just $a\cdot Id$ and thus trace is $na$.